# DRCSIM: topics not listed in UserGuide

Tags: transforms, tf2

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

1. Will the following topics be available in the VRC (in particular /tf)?

```
/rosout
/rosout_agg
/tf
/tf2_buffer_server/cancel
/tf2_buffer_server/feedback
/tf2_buffer_server/goal
/tf2_buffer_server/result
/tf2_buffer_server/status
/tf_static
```

2. What do tf2_msgs and actionlib_msgs do? The ROS documentation is a little unclear.
   Something to do with bringing up the robot, and trajectories (that are now "depracated"?)

Thanks,
Chris

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1834/drcsim:-topics-not-listed-in-userguide/) by [cga](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/66/cga/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 223 on 2013-03-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

1. Yes, all of those topics will be available in the VRC.  The [User Guide](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/DRC/UserGuide#Published_topics) has been updated to include them.
2. The `tf_static` and `tf2_buffer_server/*` topics are provided by the `tf2_buffer_server` tool, part of [tf2](http://ros.org/wiki/tf2).  This is an experimental tool, without any user-facing documentation.  In a nutshell, `tf2` is a more flexible, and, in some cases, more efficient implementation of `tf`.  The `tf2_buffer_server/*` topics constitute an [actionlib](http://ros.org/wiki/actionlib) interface, which is a sort of asynchronous request/reply mechanism.  You can use this interface to ask the `tf_buffer_server` for coordinate transforms without having to subscribe to `/tf` yourself.

---

Originally posted by [gerkey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/74/gerkey/) with karma: 1414 on 2013-03-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1